# Reorganizing extraneous data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe organized like this...

```
**Name** | **Mealtime** | **Food**  
John | 8:00 am | cereal  
John | 1:00 pm | salad  
John | 6:00 pm | pasta  
Sara | 8:00 am | yogurt  
Sara | 1:00 pm | panini  
Sara | 6:00 pm | steak  
Jake | 8:00 am | coffee  
Jake | 1:00 pm | burrito  
Jake | 6:00 pm | salad
```

And I need it to be organized like this

```
____| 8:00 am | 1:00 pm | 6:00 pm  
John | cereal | salad | pasta  
Sara | yogurt | panini | steak  
Jake | coffee | burrito | salad
```

How would I go about doing that? Note that I am not looking for an aesthetic change. Eventually I would like to select rows of data to feed into a for loop in such a way as the name can be determined from the specific food entry. For example, having grabbed the "1:00 pm" column, "salad" would direct me to John. But if I had grabbed the "6:00 pm" column, "salad" would direct me to Jake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [606]: df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Mealtime', values='Food')
Out[606]: 
Mealtime  1:00 pm 6:00 pm 8:00 am
Name                             
Jake      burrito   salad  coffee
John        salad   pasta  cereal
Sara       panini   steak  yogurt
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 0**
`numpy` slicing with `pd.factorize`

I'm going to use `pd.factorize` to produce integer values for each unique `'Name'` and `'Mealtime'`.  Along side it, I get the unique values as well.  Each integer value ends up corresponding to the element in that integer position within the unique value array.

Now I know the number of unique names and unique mealtimes, so I know the size of my eventual pivoted array.  So I create an empty one that will await to have values assigned.

Since I factorized and the factors are integer positions, I can use those to slice my empty array for assignment purposes... so I do.  I finally, put it all together with a new shiny dataframe.

```
fn, un = pd.factorize(df.Name.values)
fm, um = pd.factorize(df.Mealtime.values)
v = np.empty((un.size, um.size), dtype=object)
v[fn, fm] = df.Food.values
pd.DataFrame(v, un, um)

     8:00 am  1:00 pm 6:00 pm
John  cereal    salad   pasta
Sara  yogurt   panini   steak
Jake  coffee  burrito   salad
```

---

**Option 1**
Using `set_index`/`unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Name', 'Mealtime']).Food.unstack()

Mealtime  1:00 pm 6:00 pm 8:00 am
Name                             
Jake      burrito   salad  coffee
John        salad   pasta  cereal
Sara       panini   steak  yogurt
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
[d[m].setdefault(n, f) for n, m, f in df.values];
pd.DataFrame(d)

      1:00 pm 6:00 pm 8:00 am
Jake  burrito   salad  coffee
John    salad   pasta  cereal
Sara   panini   steak  yogurt
```

---

**Option 3**
Brute Force

```
out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.Name.unique(), columns=df.Mealtime.unique())
[out.set_value(n, m, f) for n, m, f in df.values]
out

     8:00 am  1:00 pm 6:00 pm
John  cereal    salad   pasta
Sara  yogurt   panini   steak
Jake  coffee  burrito   salad
```

---

**Timing**
Conclusion: use `pivot` for larger data with pure pandas.  Hard to beat its simplicity and ability to get the job done in this scenario.  But if you want to pivot with reckless speed, try **Option 0**.

```
%%timeit
fn, un = pd.factorize(df.Name.values)
fm, um = pd.factorize(df.Mealtime.values)
v = np.empty((un.size, um.size), dtype=object)
v[fn, fm] = df.Food.values
pd.DataFrame(v, un, um)

%timeit df.set_index(['Name', 'Mealtime']).Food.unstack()
%timeit df.pivot('Name', 'Mealtime', 'Food')
%timeit d = defaultdict(dict); [d[m].setdefault(n, f) for n, m, f in df.values]; pd.DataFrame(d)
%timeit out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.Name.unique(), columns=df.Mealtime.unique()); [out.set_value(n, m, f) for n, m, f in df.values]; out
```

*Small data*

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 300 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 541 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 656 µs per loop
```

*Larger data*

```
from string import ascii_letters

foods = np.array([
    'cereal', 'salad', 'pasta', 'yogurt',
    'panini', 'steak', 'coffee', 'burrito'
], dtype=object)
times = pd.date_range(
    pd.datetime.now().date(), periods=24, freq='H'
).strftime('%-I:00 %p')
names = list(ascii_letters)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([names, times], names=['Name', 'Mealtime'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Food=np.random.choice(foods, idx.size),
), idx).reset_index()

1000 loops, best of 3: 383 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.99 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice... planning to include a large dataset test?

Comment: The defaultdict approach did better than I thought! Colour me impressed.

Comment: All your solutions are so nice. I'm out of upvotes, looks like I'll have to go reverse some more down votes xD

Comment: You seem to be the prolific down-voter (-: I don't want to be on your bad side.

Comment: Naw... I have just as many downvotes as the next guy... it's just that... if I were to reverse an upvote, that person would lose 10 points, but reversing a down vote means +2 to that person and +1 to me and then +10 to you, so it's a win all around :)

Comment: [**Your DownVotes**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85?tab=votes&sort=downvote)  Mind you, I don't have permissions to see it.

Comment: 839^/607v according to that link. Guess I really need to relax a bit.

Comment: No, I was always hoping there existed someone who counter balanced my niceness... you're the one (-:

Comment: I'm sure there are grumps on here who've _upvoted_ 103 times out of 6,802. :p

Comment: My new **Option 0** kills it

Comment: I've kinda got it, and it's really neat. Quick question. Can't you just do: `v = df.Food.values.reshape(un.size, um.size)`?

Comment: Yes, for purposes of creating a new empty array because we can't just reshape because we don't know the order the names and mealtimes occur in.  Also, it's coincidence that this problem is well behaved in that we have all combinations of mealtimes and names represented and only once.